# SAP BI Open Doc URL for retrieving PDF

Tags: pdf, restful-url, business-objects, opendocument

In a reporting application we use, we were using BI 3.x API to produce Web reports. While doing the migration activity to 4.x version, we thought it is fine to go with open doc URL rather than doing the report generation through API.

Many of the samples I have seen uses `sIDType` and `iDocID` parameters along with `token` value to retrieve the document by constructing a URL like below `http://server:port/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?token=[LogonToken]&iDocID=[XXXX]&sIDType=CUID`

But all those URLs get HTML page as response from BI 4.x SAP Web service, the Javascript in that HTML page does the task of retrieving the PDF file.

I am just wondering if there is any way I could retrieve the PDF report as response from the BI Webservice directly ? Please assist me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can if you use the REST SDK to retrieve the document, refresh it and then export it to PDF.

In short, these are the steps:

1. Logon: `POST /biprws/logon/long`
2. Get the doc's prompts (if any) `GET /biprws/raylight/v1/documents/5690743/parameters`
3. Pass the correct values for the prompts (if any) and refresh the document: `PUT /biprws/raylight/v1/documents/5690743/parameters`
4. Export as PDF `GET /biprws/raylight/v1/documents/5690743`

That last step requires you to pass `Accept: application/pdf` in your HTTP headers to get the PDF version.

Detailed information on the REST SDK and the different steps listed above is available on [help.sap.com](http://help.sap.com/bowebi41?current=bobi#section3) (look for the manual *SAP BusinessObjects RESTful Web Service SDK User Guide for Web Intelligence and the BI Semantic Layer*).

Comment: Perfect.  I wish SAP's own documentation was this clear.  I still haven't been able to get OpenDocument working with BO 4.1 when specifying parameter values.  With BO 3.x, it worked flawlessly.   And, as usual, no one on the SAP forum is offering any solutions to my problems...

Comment: @MikeGledhill Post a new question for OpenDocument on SO, I'm sure someone will have an answer.

Comment: Yup, I just have done, thanks.  But its annoying that SAP themselves don't respond to my problems on their own forum...

Answer (score 0):

Use sOutputFormat=P  to always retrieve the PDF of the report using open doc