# Export document to PDF file with separated pages

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I am using RESTful API `/documents/id` to retrieve PDF file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35311538/3561198). But I get the single-page PDF file even if the document is very large, one big page. However if I try to export PDF by business intelligence designer I will get the PDF in multi-page format.

**How can I export the document in multi-page format by RESTful API?** In the documentation I do not see appropriate parameter, just *dpi* for PDF...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer. There is a separate API for this - `/raylight/v1/documents/27592/pages`, p. `8.1.13.2` of User Guide.