# How do I get the documentID in Business Objects Restful API?

Tags: restful-url, business-objects

I'm trying to figure out how to download a PDF from the BOE restful API.

I've been following the answer from ƘɌỈSƬƠƑ here:
[SAP BI Open Doc URL for retrieving pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310121/sap-bi-open-doc-url-for-retrieving-pdf)

I was able to accomplish step 1 (getting the token).

But on the second step, it mentions using the documentID.

e.g.

```
/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/5690743/parameters
```

On the front end of BOE, if I click on the report, and choose Properties, it shows me that the "ID/CUID" is:

```
ID, CUID:746001, AdgNq_GsaqhOqnzc4gRN_Jg
```

Does that mean the "DocumentID" is 746001?

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct ID, because when I hit:

```
/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/746001/parameters
```

I get:

```
<error>
   <error_code>100</error_code>
   <message>Rule not respected (Argument 'reportIds' must not be null)</message>
</error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to obtain prompt information (/parameters endpoint).

I think you are using the correct ID since the error is on the report. You obtain a `404 Not Found` response status, if the document does not exist.

After a successful login, simply call `/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/5690743` and add to your request an header with name `Accept` and value `application/pdf`. Of course the `X-SAP-LogonToken` should also be provided.

It will export the whole document. If you only need a specific report, you need to retrieve its ID first. Call the URI `/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/5690743/reports` with  `Accept` header equals to `application/json`.

Choose one of the report, and get its ID (for example, in my case reportID equals 1234). Then you can export the report as a PDF by calling the URI:  `/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/5690743/reports/1234` with `Accept` header equals to `application/pdf`.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to the difference between a document versus a report.  (i'm not really a poweruser).  After logging into the management console, I just click on "Folders", then navigate down to the report that I want.  Is the containing folder the "document"?  I know, if I r-click->properties on the report, it shows my the "ID, CUID", but I have no idea what the "document" is.  Can you elaborate, or point me in the right direction to learn more?  I tried googling it, but I can't see to find any explanation.

Comment: The document is what you call a report.
Each Web Intelligence document can have several 'tabs' which are called reports.

Comment: When I hit: /biprws/raylight/v1/documents/746001, it gives me an error: The resource of type 'Document' with identifier '746001' does not exist.  I am able to navigate to the report in CMC, then rclick->properties.  It shows "ID, CUID:746001, AdgNq_GsaqhOqnzc4gRN_Jg"  That means 746001 is the documentID doesn't it?  Or am I still not understanding?

Comment: Yes, it is the good document identifier. Are you sure that you are querying the same CMS in both cases ? (perhaps you have on prod environment and on test environment, in this case document id are not the same)

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I think I'm on the same CMS.  I found that I'm on an older version of BOE than what the documentation says, so i think i'll need to see if it works after I do the updates.  I'm showing that I'm still on Support Pack 2.   I'm guessing that's probably the problem, but I'll need to see when I can run updates without affecting other users on our system.  Thanks for all your help.